# Multiplication operators are sectorial

Tags: reference-request, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Consider the multiplication operator $M_a$ on $L^p(M)$, where $M$ is a Riemannian manifold, and $a$ is a non-negative function. An operator $A$ is said to be sectorial if there exists $\theta \in (0, \pi)$ such that (a) $\sigma (A) \subset \Sigma_\theta \cup \{0\}$, where $\Sigma_\theta = \{\lambda \in \mathbb{C} : \vert \text{arg } \lambda\vert < \theta\}$ and (b) there exists $C_\theta$ such that $\Vert \lambda R(\lambda, A)\Vert \leq C_\theta$ whenever $\lambda \in \mathbb{C} \setminus (\Sigma_\theta \cup \{0\} )$.

Now, my question is: why are multiplication operators sectorial? All I can see is $\Vert R(\lambda, M_a)\Vert = d(\lambda, \sigma (M_a))^{-1} = \frac{1}{\vert \text{Im}(\lambda)\vert}$. This does not give (b) above as far as I can see.

Comment: It makes if you consider your operator now in a sector with angle as you write.

Comment: In the second sector of the fourth line you have to add $\pi/2$ to the angle.

Comment: Why is $d(\lambda, \sigma(M_a)) = | \text{Im}(\lambda) |$?